# CakePHP: Adding uniquer token to links to make sure correct user is clicking them

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to implement in my app tokens for user links such as: `domain.com/logout/5hDQ5VxNIEOv` where that string is unique to that user (per session) so that it makes sure that the user is the correct one when doing an action.

So it's a unique code generated for a user that you add to the url, then check whenever the user follows that url. If the codes match, cool; if not, 404 or redirect or whatever.

Can anyone help / give me guidance for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is usually implemented using Cookies and Sessions. Cake does this very transparently with the SessionComponent and AuthComponent. It's the same thing really, except that the unique value is transferred in an HTTP `Cookie` header instead of the URL. That's preferable, since you don't usually want such temporary values in the URL (think bookmarking or sharing links).

Don't reinvent this particular wheel unless you have a requirement against cookies.